# How to start service after reboot device in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I want start my `Service` after reboot device, I write below codes but when reboot device not start `Service`.
**Manifest:**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".alarm1.alarm1"></activity>

        <receiver android:name=".alarm1.AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Will not be called unless the application explicitly enables it -->
        <receiver android:name=".alarm1.DeviceBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Activity code:**

```
public class alarm1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm1);

            /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        findViewById(R.id.startAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                start();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancel();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.stopAlarmAt10).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startAt10();
            }
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 8000;

        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void startAt10() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 1000 * 60 * 20;

        /* Set the alarm to start at 10:30 AM */
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

        Toast.makeText(alarm1.this, "Start at 17:11", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        /* Repeating on every 20 minutes interval */
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000 * 60 * 3, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**AlarmReceiver codes:**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**DeviceBootReceiver codes:**

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            /* Setting the alarm here */
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            int interval = 8000;
            manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this and when reboot device start `Service`?

Comment: Have you added the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission to your Manifest?

Comment: @user13, no i'm not added this permission

Answer (score 3):

Add permissions in Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Add receiver entry in Manifest.

```
 <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".alarm1.DeviceBootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to

1. Request a permission

and

2. Explicitly enable the receiver.

The permission goes in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Then when the user sets an alarm (for example your `start` method), enable the boot receiver:

```
ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, DeviceBootReceiver.class);
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

When the user cancels all alarms, you should disable the boot receiver using a similar piece of code.